# Using lsof to find which process is connected to a unix file socket

Tags: network, macos, unix

I have a server application that binds a unix file socket on `/var/run/appsocket`.

I have multiple clients which connect to this unix file socket, and I want to be able to determine which PID is connected to this unix file socket.

**What I've tried:**

```
sudo lsof /var/run/appsocket
```

Displays the following:

> appserver 101 appuser    6u  unix 0x5d3497ad372af941      0t0      /var/run/appsocket
>
> appserver 101 appuser    9u  unix 0x5d3497ad3aa380a9      0t0      /var/run/appsocket

This displays which process created the unix file socket, but not the one who is using it. If I list open files by my app client, I see that it is using the file handle 0x5d3497ad372af941 (from the list above).

I've tried using several solutions from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16300/whos-got-the-other-end-of-this-unix-socketpair), but nothing worked.
I'm using lsof 4.89 and `-E` is not supported for some reason.

How can I make this connection between the file handle and the process which opened it?

**EDIT**

```
sudo lsof /var/run/appsocket | awk '{print $6}' | uniq | xargs -I {} sh -c "sudo lsof -U | grep {}" | awk '{print $1}' | uniq
```

Does the trick, but is not optimal whatsoever...

Comment: Try netstat, that does socket connections too